# Finding x and z value in the direction of another object

Tags: unity, c#

In my game you can drive a car and it has an arrow point to an object you need to drive towards. The arrow pops up above the car using the same x and z value as the car but adding 2 to the y value. What I am trying to do is push the arrow out a little bit toward the object it is pointing to. This way it looks like it is rotating in a circle around the car instead of rotating about it's own center point.

This is what I am doing right now:

```
if (!(Vector3.Angle(car.transform.forward, obj.transform.position - car.transform.position) < 40f))
{
    arrow.SetActive(true);
    temp = car.transform.position;
    temp.y = car.transform.position.y + 2f;
    arrow.transform.position = temp;
    temp = obj.transform.position;
    temp.y = arrow.transform.position.y;
    arrow.transform.LookAt(temp);
}
```

Comment: Added a few commented lines of code, in case it's only *almost* good enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (...)
{
    carPosition = car.transform.position;
    objectPosition = obj.transform.position;

    //Calculate the car-to-object vector
    carToObjectDirection = objectPosition - carPosition;

    //Make sure it's flat
    carToObjectDirection.y = 0;

    //Make length convenient for multiplication
    carToObjectDirection.Normalize();

    //Move arrowPosition away from (0,0) in carToObjectDirection by offsetLength amount
    arrowPosition = (carToObjectDirection * offsetLength);

    //Move the offset arrow to just above the car
    arrowPosition += carPosition;
    arrowPosition.y += 2;

    arrow.SetActive(true);
    arrow.transform.position = arrowPosition;

    //Uncomment to prevent the arrow from pointing excessively upward or downward
    //LookAt.y is clamped to within 10% of arrowPosition.y
    //objectPosition.y = max(objectPosition.y, arrowPosition.y * 0.9f);
    //objectPosition.y = min(objectPosition.y, arrowPosition.y * 1.1f);

    //Uncomment to keep the arrow parallel to the XZ-plane
    //objectPosition.y = arrowPosition.y;

    //Slightly less parallel (2 lower than lookat) (always points slightly downward)
    //objectPosition.y = carPosition.y;

    arrow.transform.LookAt(objectPosition);
}
```

[image: DIAGRAM]